# the sound of "pfft" in real life

Tags: pronunciation

I think I know, but I'm not sure. Dictionary sound is different from real life. Does it sound like "chi"?

(weirdly I couldn't find this with google or youtube)

Comment: No, not like chi. You make a p sound with no vowel and just push the air out and let your lips flop.It's really hard to describe. :) In my version, there is no t sound at all.

Answer (score 1):

It just sounds like "ffff" or "fffft." It's the sound of air being pushed through your lips quickly with these sounds and no vocalizations.

I know what you're talking about with the "chi" sound. It's a different sound, but the meaning is similar. And it's the same idea — a consonant + air and no throat sound. I'd say "pfft" is more dismissive, and "chi" more just about emphasizing a feeling.

Comment: @Lambie I just wanted to say "thank you".  But the website requires 15 or so characters.

Comment: @kai  Boy, am I dumb. :)

Answer (score 1):

> (weirdly I couldn't find this with google or youtube)

Try searching for **pronunciation of pfft**  You will find it in several online dictionaries (and YT). [pfft](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/pfft)

The odd thing is that the pronunciation in those dictionaries doesn't sound anything like how I always imagined the sound.

I agree with the description by @Lambie - maybe the dictionaries are wrong.